# replacing unique ID's with a sequence of numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph in which the x-axis is the date (each tick is 1 day), and each tick of the y-axis represents a uniquely identified individual (a fish).  Then, for each individual each day, I will plot a point to show if each individual was detected on a certain day.

My issue is that I have many thousand detections to plot, and about 400 individuals.  The individuals uniquely identifying numbers are quite large (for example: 161795550 and 165705763 are two of the 400 unique IDs).  Some individuals are only seen for a few days, some for a few hundred.

THE ISSUE: plotting it this way (using ggplot2) makes the y-axis impossibly spread out between the low and high unique IDs, and with ggplot2 there is no way to break the axis.  So, my thoughts on a solution were to renumber the unique IDs as a sequence from 1 to 400, as a way of controlling the spread on the y-axis.  I could do this manually, but it would take a long time.  Is there any good way to automate this renaming?

Here is some code that could be used to recreate an applied situation, where I would want to rename the three unique ID's (165705763,161795422,161795351) as (1,2,3) (except there would be 400 IDs in the real life problem).

```
a<-c("165705763","165705763","165705763","165705763","165705763","161795422","161795351","161795351","161795351")
b<-c("Seine","Seine","Seine","Seine","Seine","Seine","HookAndLine","HookAndLine","HookAndLine")
f<-c("2010-10-25","2010-10-18 ","2010-10-30","2010-11-12","2010-10-29","2010-10-16","2010-10-25","2010-10-16","2010-10-18")
d<-cbind(a,b,f)
```

Any other solutions are welcome!

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Your ID is a character, not a numeric, thus ggplot will treat these as factors and hence a categorical scale, not numeric. There shouldn't be a problem, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It was numeric, as an integer.  I saved it as a character, and ggplot2 dealt with it perfectly!

Comment: instead of converting it to character, you could just add `scale_y_discrete()` to your plot

Comment: @user1399311 Nice one. Or simply use `ggplot(dat, aes(x=f, y=factor(a))`

Answer (score 1):

Andrie's comment led to a blatantly simple solution.  The original data had the ID's as the class 'Integer'.  I merely reclassed the ID's to be characters, and ggplot2 scaled the y-axis automatically